# How to resolve automatic return type - C++ (templates)

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a dotProduct methods with these signatures:

```
template<typename It, typename It2>
typename DetermineResultType< typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<It2>::value_type>::Result dotProduct(It source, It2 source, const size_t size);

template<typename R, typename It, typename It2>
R dotProduct(It source, It2 source, const size_t size);
```

Everything works ok, until I try:

```
char * s, * s2;
int result = dotProduct<int>(s, s2, 3);
```

With this I get error that `std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type` is not defined.

How can I resolve this so that I can automatically determine result type for the first declaration? (The name of methods must stay same). I employ some rules to determine the resulting type, but this is not important.

Basically the problem boils down to whether `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` is defined - when non-specialized std::iterator_traits is used. Can I detect this somehow?
If not what other options do I have?

Ok, now the example down works, but how do I do the same trick my DetermineComputationType aka DetermineResultType is defined this way: ???

```
    //! Template IF predicate implementation
  template <bool B, typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult> 
 class TemplateIf {
 public:
   //! The result of template IF predicate
   typedef TrueResult Result;
 };

 //! Template IF predicate implementation - specialization for false condition
 template <typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult>
 class TemplateIf<false, TrueResult, FalseResult> {
 public:
   //! The result of template IF predicate
   typedef FalseResult Result;
 };



  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  class DetermineComputationType {
  public:
    //! The determined result type
    // If (isSpecialized(T1) && isSpecialized(T2)) {
    typedef typename TemplateIf< std::numeric_limits<T1>::is_specialized && std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_specialized,
      // If (! isInteger(T1) && isInteger(T2) )
      //   return T1;
      typename TemplateIf< ! std::numeric_limits<T1>::is_integer && std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_integer, T1,
      // Else if (! isInteger(T2) && isInteger(T1) )
      //   return T2;
      typename TemplateIf< ! std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_integer && std::numeric_limits<T1>::is_integer, T2,
      // Else if ( sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2) )
      //   return T1;
      typename TemplateIf< (sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)), T1,
      // Else if ( sizeof(T2) > sizeof(T1) )
      //   return T2;
      typename TemplateIf< (sizeof(T2) > sizeof(T1)), T2,
      // Else if ( isSigned(T2) )
      //   return T1;
      // Else
      //   return T2; 
      // }
      typename TemplateIf< std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_signed, T1, T2>::Result >::Result >::Result >::Result >::Result,
      // Else if ( sizeof(T2> > sizeof(T1) )
      //   return T2;
      // Else
      //   return T1;
      typename TemplateIf< (sizeof(T2) > sizeof(T1)), T2, T1 >::Result >::Result Result;
  };


   /*!
\brief Helper class for computation type determination - works for 3 types 

\tparam T1 The first type for computation type determination
\tparam T2 The second type for computation type determination 
\tparam T3 The third type for computation type determination

The result is computed in order: (T1, (T2, T3))
*/
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class DetermineComputationType2 {
public:
//! The computation type result
typedef typename DetermineComputationType<T1, typename DetermineComputationType<T2, T3>::Result >::Result Result;
 };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class DetermineReturnComputationType {
public:    
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T1>::value_type T1Type;
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T2>::value_type T2Type;    
typedef typename DetermineComputationType<T1Type, T2Type>::Result Result;
};

//! For description see cpputil::dotProduct()
 template <typename R, typename Ct, typename It, typename It2>
 inline R dotProductRCtItIt2(It source, It2 source2, const size_t size) {
   Ct result = Ct();
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     result += static_cast<Ct>(source[i]) * static_cast<Ct>(source2[i]);

   return static_cast<R>(result);
  }


/*!
\brief Returns the dot product of vectors

\param[in] source The iterator to the start of source vector
\param[in] source2 The iterator to the start of second source vector    
\param[in] size The size of vector(s)
*/
template <typename R, typename Ct, typename It, typename It2>
inline R dotProduct(It source, It2 source2, const size_t size) {
  return arithmeticsInternal::dotProductRCtItIt2<R, Ct, It, It2>(source, source2, size);  
}

//! Convenience method - see above for description
template <typename R, typename It, typename It2>
inline R dotProduct(It source, It2 source2, const size_t size) {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type ItType;
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It2>::value_type It2Type;
  typedef typename arithmeticsInternal::DetermineComputationType2<R, ItType, It2Type>::Result Ct;

 return arithmeticsInternal::dotProductRCtItIt2<R, Ct, It, It2>(source, source2, size);
}

//! Convenience method - see above for description
template <typename It, typename It2>
inline typename arithmeticsInternal::DetermineReturnComputationType<It, It2>::Result dotProduct(It source, It2 source2, const size_t size) {
 //typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type ItType;
 //typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It2>::value_type It2Type;
 typedef typename arithmeticsInternal::DetermineReturnComputationType<It, It2>::Result R;

 return arithmeticsInternal::dotProductRCtItIt2<R, R, It, It2>(source, source2, size);  
 }
```

Comment: Why would there be iterator traits for a builtin type? `For every iterator type, a corresponding specialization of iterator_traits class template shall exist...`

Comment: In the second declaration, you are using "typename R", but when you use typename it should be something like "typename X::Y".

Comment: Default std::iterator_traits<T> forwards the declaration of type by typedef: typedef typename _Iter::value_type value_type; Now when it tries second method the one with R - it tries to find the value_type as nested type in int.

Comment: You are wanting a dotProduct function where you can either explicitly specify the resulting type or have it determined automatically?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get a dotProduct template function that will either deduce the return type or allow you to specify it explicitly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;

template<typename It, typename It2> struct DetermineResultType;

template<>
struct DetermineResultType<char,char> {
  typedef int Result;
};

template <typename It1,typename It2>
struct DotProduct {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It1>::value_type VT1;
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It2>::value_type VT2;
  typedef typename DetermineResultType<VT1,VT2>::Result Result;
};

template<typename Result,typename It, typename It2>
Result dotProduct(It source1, It2 source2, const size_t size)
{
  Result sum = 0;
  for (size_t i=0; i!=size; ++i) {
    sum += *source1 * *source2;
  }
  return sum;
}

template<typename It1, typename It2>
typename DotProduct<It1,It2>::Result
  dotProduct(It1 source1, It2 source2, const size_t size)
{
  typedef typename DotProduct<It1,It2>::Result Result;
  return dotProduct<Result>(source1,source2,size);
}


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  const char *s1 = "abc";
  const char *s2 = "def";
  cerr << dotProduct<int>(s1,s2,3) << "\n";
  cerr << dotProduct(s1,s2,3) << "\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If the first parameter is not an iterator, then the compiler will fail to instantiate DotProduct<>, because it will not be able to determine the type of VT1.  SFINAE will then eliminate that overload.

Comment: @MarkB: Not quite!  My version allows SFINAE to eliminate the other function when the first parameter isn't an iterator, but I'm not sure why that doesn't happen without the intermediate class.

Comment: Do I get it correctly that this depends on template<typename It, typename It2> struct DetermineResultType; not being defined for non-partial specialized version?

Comment: I have put up how the result type is determined. How do I employ that trick of yours for non-trivial determination using TemplateIf constructs?

Comment: @MarkB: I've added a short explanation as to why this works, although I still don't understand why SFINAE doesn't apply if we try to use DetermineResultType directly in the dotProduct declaration.

Comment: @PavelCelba: I don't see how your more complex class would cause it not to work.

Comment: It works for me when I edit your example, but in production code it still doesn't - still that std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type problem.

Comment: I have edited my post above to include all the code which is relevant for dotProduct computation. Maybe you will see the problem which I'm unable to spot.

Comment: Ok, got it - this is also trying to determine from this one: //! Convenience method - see above for description
template <typename It> 
inline typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type dotProduct(It source, const size_t size) {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type ItType;

  return arithmeticsInternal::dotProductRCtIt<ItType, ItType, It>(source, size);
}

Comment: The version with single source parameter. :-)